# How to get Javascript Const to work with Grunt Uglify?

Tags: javascript, constants, gruntjs

I am trying to use javascript Const with Grunt Uglify but receive the error:

> Unexpected token: keyword «const».

I have done a little googling and tried

```
npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

However that did not work.

It was stated I needed to add the following to my Plugins array...

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

new TerserPlugin({
    parallel: true,
    terserOptions: {
        ecma: 6,
    },
}),
```

I wasn't sure exactly where to add this though? Does it go in my grunt file.js?

Additionally I also saw that a fix might be to use the harmony branch of grunt-contrib-uglify. But I fear this method is out of date?

Ultimately I am attempting to code a cookie consent pop up.  Does anyone know how to get Const to work with grunt uglify?

Or does anyone have a better recommendation for coding cookie consent pop ups?

Many thanks.

Edit: Adding grunt file as requested

```
// Load Grunt
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Tasks
    sass: { // Begin Sass Plugin (this takes all your scss files and compiles them into style.css)
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'assets/scss/my-theme',
          src: ['**/*.scss'],
          dest: 'dist/css',
          ext: '.css'
      }]
      }
    },
    postcss: { // Begin Post CSS Plugin (this applies browser prefixes to your compiled style.css in 'dist' folder)
      options: {
        map: false,
        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer')({
                overrideBrowserslist: ['last 2 versions']
              })
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        src: 'dist/css/style.css'
      }
    },
    cssmin: { // Begin CSS Minify Plugin (this takes your style.css file from 'dist', minifies it and creates style.min.css)
      target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'dist/css',
          src: ['style.css', '!*.min.css'],
          dest: 'dist/css',
          ext: '.min.css'
    }]
      }
    },
    uglify: { // Begin JS Uglify Plugin (this takes your my-theme js files in 'assets', minifies them and creates script.min.js in 'dist' folder)
      build: {
        src: ['assets/js/my-theme/*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/js/script.min.js'
      }
    },
    watch: { // Compile everything into one task with Watch Plugin (this watches for any changes to scss and js files, so make sure it is pointing to your 'my-theme' CSS and JS folders in 'assets')
      css: {
        files: 'assets/scss/my-theme/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass', 'postcss', 'cssmin']
      },
      js: {
        files: 'assets/js/my-theme/**/*.js',
        tasks: ['uglify']
      }
    }
  });
  // Load Grunt plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-terser');

  // Register Grunt tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

Comment: Are you using grunt or webpack? This doesn't seem to fit in my eyes. Either you're using grunt and try to use a webpack plugin, or vice versa. Please specify your toolchain and post your gruntfile (webpack file respectively).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you made me realise I was mixing up commands. I am definitely using grunt. Since your comment I ran 'npm install grunt-terser --save-dev' and then added the following to my grunt file 'grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-terser');' I have also edited my original comment to include my grunt file. I am still getting the same error, despite making the updates in this comment.